# Fractional ffmpeg timecode in draw text

Tags: ffmpeg

I got a frame rate under 1 and can't seem to get ffmpeg to stamp the time code

Doesn't work

```
ffmpeg -start_number 0 -framerate 32 -y -i "f0_t%d_i0_ch1_c0_r0_z0_mqdic.jpg" -vframes 32 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=DejaVuSans.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':timecode_rate=0.28571:fontcolor=red:fontsize=64: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1,setpts=PTS" -pix_fmt yuv420p  -c:v libx264 "part9_dynamics_slower_sampling_z0.avi"
```

with an error

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 00000283dbab5f00] Timecode frame rate must be specified
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000283dbab58c0] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=DejaVuSans.ttf:timecode=00\:00\:00\:00:timecode_rate=0.28571:fontcolor=red:fontsize=64: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Works as expected

```
ffmpeg -start_number 0 -framerate 32 -y -i "f0_t%d_i0_ch1_c0_r0_z0_mqdic.jpg" -vframes 32 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=DejaVuSans.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':timecode_rate=1:fontcolor=red:fontsize=64: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1,setpts=PTS" -pix_fmt yuv420p  -c:v libx264 "part9_dynamics_slower_sampling_z0.avi"
```

In one case `timecode_rate=0.28571` and in the other `timecode_rate=1`

So, how do I stamp in the correct, `0.28571` frame rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timecode_rate value is rounded and then applied, so `0.2857` gets rounded down to 0, which is considered invalid. That error message should be refined.

Since you seem to want timecode value to increase by 0.2857 after each 32 frames, you can supply a custom text value

```
text='%{e\:0.2857*n/32}'
```

Remove the timecode and timecode_rate options.